# Multiple email attachment failure

Tags: error, exception, apex-email-service, send-email

I have below code to send multiple email attachments in a single email which is throwing below error. Can some one please tell me what's wrong here?

**Code Snippet**

```
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
       Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        if(getSelectedSize() > 0)
        { if(recordtypes.contains('ABS_Compliance_Incidents_abv'))
            {
            PageReference pdf = Page.CompIncidentTransactionsAttachment;
            pdf.getParameters().put('Ids',Ids ); //
            pdf.setRedirect(true);//false

            Blob b = pdf.getContent();


            efa.setFileName('ComplianceIncidentReport.pdf');
            efa.setBody(b); 
            }                  
            //email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});        

        if(recordtypes.contains('Sample_Compliance_Incidents_abv'))  
           {
           PageReference pdf1 = Page.CompIncidentTransactionsAttachmentSample;
            pdf1.getParameters().put('Ids',Ids ); //
            pdf1.setRedirect(true);//false

            Blob b1 = pdf1.getContent();
           // Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

            efa1.setFileName('SampleIncidentReport.pdf');
            efa1.setBody(b1);  
           }    
           Integer interSample=[select count() from Compliance_Incident_abv__c where Id =:Ids1 and Recordtype.developername='Sample_Compliance_Incidents_abv'];
           Integer interABS=[select count() from Compliance_Incident_abv__c where Id =:Ids1 and Recordtype.developername='ABS_Compliance_Incidents_abv'];
            if(interSample==0)
             {email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});}         
           else if(interABS==0)
               {email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa1});}*/

           else {
           email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa,efa1}); 
            }

        }

        // Sets the paramaters of the email
        email.setSubject(Subject);

        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
        if(ccAddresses.size() > 0 && ccAddresses[0] != null && ccAddresses[0] != '') 
        {
            //ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, toAddresses + ' ' + ccAddresses + ccAddresses.size() + toAddresses.size()));
            email.setCCAddresses( ccAddresses );
        }

        email.setPlainTextBody( Body);

        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   
        sendEmail=true;//Control viz of Send btn.
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Your Email has been successfully Sent'));
```

**Error**

System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, No body supplied for the file attachment.: [fileAttachments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be one reason:
1. Record Types are not matching in `if`. Try below sample code.

```
   List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> efaList = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();

    if(getSelectedSize() > 0)
    { 
       if(recordtypes.contains('ABS_Compliance_Incidents_abv'))
       {
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

        PageReference pdf = Page.CompIncidentTransactionsAttachment;
        pdf.getParameters().put('Ids',Ids ); //
        pdf.setRedirect(true);//false

        Blob b = pdf.getContent();


        efa.setFileName('ComplianceIncidentReport.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b); 
        efaList.add(efa);
        Integer interABS=[select count() from Compliance_Incident_abv__c where Id =:Ids1 and Recordtype.developername='ABS_Compliance_Incidents_abv'];

        if(interABS==0)
        {
           email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
        }

       }                        

       if(recordtypes.contains('Sample_Compliance_Incidents_abv'))  
       {
        PageReference pdf1 = Page.CompIncidentTransactionsAttachmentSample;
        pdf1.getParameters().put('Ids',Ids ); //
        pdf1.setRedirect(true);//false

        Blob b1 = pdf1.getContent();

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

        efa.setFileName('SampleIncidentReport.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b1);
        Integer interSample=[select count() from Compliance_Incident_abv__c where Id =:Ids1 and Recordtype.developername='Sample_Compliance_Incidents_abv'];
        if(interSample==0)
       {
           email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

        }  
       }    
    }

    // Sets the paramaters of the email
    email.setSubject(Subject);

    email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
    if(ccAddresses.size() > 0 && ccAddresses[0] != null && ccAddresses[0] != '') 
    {
        //ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, toAddresses + ' ' + ccAddresses + ccAddresses.size() + toAddresses.size()));
        email.setCCAddresses( ccAddresses );
    }

    email.setPlainTextBody( Body);

    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   
    sendEmail=true;//Control viz of Send btn.
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Your Email has been successfully Sent'));
```